# DX11 Draw a simple 2D line without the use of extraneous libraries

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm looking for the simplest way to draw a line between two screen coordinates within the context of a Present call. I'm quite a beginner when it comes to DX11, but I was shocked that there was no rudimentary "simple" way to draw a line.

To re-iterate, I'm looking for the easiest way to draw a 2D line with access to the IDXGISwapChain and access to DX functions:

```
HRESULT __stdcall D3D11Present(IDXGISwapChain* This, UINT SyncInterval, UINT Flags) {
   // do anything here
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3D11: How to draw a simple pixel aligned line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898107/d3d11-how-to-draw-a-simple-pixel-aligned-line)

Comment: No, this seems more general than that - like asking "why does DirectX have no DrawLine function", rather than "how do I draw a line with a width of one pixel".

Comment: Also, the answers on that question are vague and I haven't really seen a complete answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to draw a single-pixel line with Direct3D 11 is to use [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki) and the `PrimitiveBatch` class in combination with `BasicEffect`:

```
std::unique_ptr<DirectX::CommonStates> m_states;
std::unique_ptr<DirectX::BasicEffect> m_effect;
std::unique_ptr<DirectX::PrimitiveBatch<DirectX::VertexPositionColor>> m_batch;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout> m_inputLayout;
```

…

```
m_states = std::make_unique<CommonStates>(m_d3dDevice.Get());

m_effect = std::make_unique<BasicEffect>(m_d3dDevice.Get());
m_effect->SetVertexColorEnabled(true);

void const* shaderByteCode;
size_t byteCodeLength;

m_effect->GetVertexShaderBytecode(&shaderByteCode, &byteCodeLength);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(VertexPositionColor::InputElements,
        VertexPositionColor::InputElementCount,
        shaderByteCode, byteCodeLength,
        m_inputLayout.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));

m_batch = std::make_unique<PrimitiveBatch<VertexPositionColor>>(m_d3dContext.Get());
```

…

```
m_d3dContext->OMSetBlendState( m_states->Opaque(), nullptr, 0xFFFFFFFF );
m_d3dContext->OMSetDepthStencilState( m_states->DepthNone(), 0 );
m_d3dContext->RSSetState( m_states->CullNone() );

m_effect->Apply(m_d3dContext.Get());

m_d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(m_inputLayout.Get());

m_batch->Begin();

VertexPositionColor v1(Vector3(-1.f, -1.0f, 0.5f), Colors::Yellow);
VertexPositionColor v2(Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f), Colors::Yellow);

m_batch->DrawLine(v1, v2);

m_batch->End();
```

> Direct3D can natively draw single-pixel 'textured-lines', but typically if you need anything fancy like wide-lines, etc. use [Direct2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Direct2D/direct2d-portal) to do the drawing since it's a full vector-based renderer.
>
> If you want to use DirectX 12, see [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please answer in the context of D3D11Present?

Comment: Well, you'd get the backbuffer from the swapchain via DXGI, create a render target view, bind it as your RTV, set the render viewport, and then use the code above to. Of course, there's no such system method as ``D3D11Present``.

Comment: Note you asked for the 'simplest' way to draw a line, not the "most detailed code example that uses no other code". In that case, see the traditional [Tutorial03](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/master/Direct3D11Tutorials/Tutorial03/Tutorial03.cpp)